# Scale button icons in Qt on Android?

Tags: android, c++, css, qt

I created some icons for buttons in my application. I think this search field looks nice:

[image: image description]

Or does it? This is what you get on Samsung Galaxy S6 with that crazy-ass DPI screen:

[image: image description]

Qt did scale font size and field size as I wanted, but the button icon is exactly the same size on both pictures. Here's full scale image for comparison:

[image: image description]

I used Qt Designer to add the icon from resources:

[image: image description]

So what I need is to get Qt to properly make my icons larger or smaller so that they fit the button. I actually expected that it will happen automatically, silly me.